# Core Data's Limits, can Core Data be used as a Serverside Technology?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I've found no clear answer so far, but maybe I've searched the wrong way.
My Question is, can Core Data to be used as a Persitence Storage for a Server Project? Where are Core Data's Limits, how much Data can be handled with Core Data and SQLite? SQLite should handle a lot of Data very well according to their website. I know of a properitary Java Persitence Manager with an Oracle DB as Storage that handles Millions of Entries and 3000 Clients without Problems. For my own Project I wonder if I can use Core Data on the Server Side for User Mangament and intern microblogging, texting with up to 5000 clients. Will it handle such big amounts of Data or do I have to manage something like that myself? Does anyone happend to have experience with huge amounts if Data and Core Data?

Thank you

twickl

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't advise using Core Data for a server side project. Core Data was designed to handle the data of individual, object-oriented applications therefore it lacks many of the common features of dedicated server software such as easily handling multiple simultaneous accesses.

Really, the only circumstance where I would advise using it is when the server side logic is very complex and the number of users small. For example, if you wanted to write an in house web app and have almost all the logic on the server, then Core Data might serve well.

Apple used to have WebObjects which was a package to manage servers using an object-oriented DB much like Core Data. (Core Data was inspired by a component of WebObjects called Enterprise Objects.) However, IIRC Apple no longer supports WebObjects for external use.

Your better off using one of the many dedicated server packages out there than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience using Core Data in the manner you describe, but my understanding of the architecture leads me to believe that it could be used, depending on how you plan to query and manipulate the data.

Core Data is very good at maintaining an object graph and using faults to bring parts into memory as needed. In that manner, it could be good on a server for reducing memory requirements even with a large data set.

Core Data is not very good at manipulating collections of objects without loading them into memory, making a change, and writing them back out to disk. [Brent Simmons wrote a blog post about this](http://inessential.com/2010/02/26/on_switching_away_from_core_data), where he decide to stop using Core Data for some of his RSS reader's model objects because an operation like "mark all as read" didn't scale. While you would like to be able to say something like `UPDATE articles SET status = 'read'`, Core Data must load each article, set its status property, then write it back to disk.

This isn't because Apple engineers are stupid, but because the query layer can't make assumptions about the storage layer (you could be using XML instead of SQLite) and it also must take into account cascading changes and the fact that some article objects may already be loaded into memory and will need to be updated there.

Note that you can also write your own storage providers for Core Data, see Aaron Hillegass's [BNRPersistence](http://github.com/hillegass/BNRPersistence) project. So if Core Data was "mostly good" you might be able to improve on it for your application.

So, a possible answer to your question is that Core Data may be appropriate to your application, as long as you do not need to rely on batch updates to large number of objects. In general, no algorithm or data structure is appropriate for every scenario. Engineering is about wisely choosing between trade-offs. You won't find anything that works well for many clients in every case. It always matters what you are doing.